# Fetching from upstream github repository fails by hanging up

Tags: git, github

Why is my git fetch failing with a:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am a collaborator on a private project and have successfully forked the project. I have setup a remote using the github example:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/{upstream owner}/{upstream project}.git
```

I can see the remote was added using "git -v show -n upstream"

```
Fetch URL: git://github.com/{upstream owner}/{upstream project}.git
Push  URL: git://github.com/{upstream owner}/{upstream project}.git
```

I know my ssh key works:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi miketempleman! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

yet when I try to update my local repository from the upstream repository:

```
mike@ununtu-11:~/{directory}$ git fetch upstream
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Apologies for such a stupid question.

Comment: Has pushing to the upstream repo ever worked? Are you sure the upstream owner has setup appropriate permissions for your user account?

Comment: I am just trying to update my local repository with upstream changes. More read access, in other words. But it is a simple repository, so the documentation I have read indicates that I have read/write access to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the `git://` read-only URIs are not available for private repos so that they are not world-readable (i.e. you can only get at the repo if you are authorized).

Try with a different remote URI:

```
git remote set-url upstream git@github.com:{upstream owner}/{upstream project}.git
```

or, alternatively with HTTPS:

```
git remote set-url upstream https://{your username}@github.com/{upstream owner}/{upstream project}.git
```

Comment: that did the trick. So hopefully anyone else trying to use private repositories on git for shared development will find your link!